# TWM f.exec automatic

Tags: twm

When executing an application either through the terminal or through the TWM menu, it waits for you to click button 1 in order to continue with the process.

I think the question is understood, when executing `xterm` or any application like `firefox`, to be able to use it I need to click, since when executing it it appears in the background, I can move the window to the position I want, but until I click with button 1 is not operative.

How could I do it, so that it was automatic?

I have tried to combine the function `f.exec` and `f.raise` from `twm`, but I can't get anything. There has to be the solution in the `f.exec`.

My `system.twmrc` is nothing special, it's pretty much like the default.